# Adding to a subplot figure using a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

My question is pretty simple. I have this function that creates a certain graph for each column in a dataframe. The output however is 7 separate graphs. I am able to make a 4x2 subplot like this:

```
f, axarr = plt.subplots(4, 2, figsize = (10, 10))
```

to get [this empty chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tty9.png)

here is the code for my plots. How can/should I make it fill in the subplot instead of returning 7 separate plots? including the head of the data frames for reference

```
for index in weights.columns:    
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 6))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    ##this gets the bottom axis to be in the middle so you can see 
    ##clearly positive or negative returns
    ax.spines['left'].set_position(('data', 0.0))
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data', 0.0))

    ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
    ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')

    ax.set_ylabel('{} One month forward return'.format(index))
    ax.set_xlabel('Percent of Max Exposure')

    ##get the ticks in percentage format

    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda y, _: '{:.0%}'.format(y)))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda x, _: '{:.0%}'.format(x)))

    plt.title('One Month Forward {} Returns Versus Total Exposure'.format(index))
    plt.scatter(weights_scaled[index], forward_returns[index], marker = 'o')
```

weights_scaled.head()

Out[415]: 
            US Equities  Dev Ex-U.S. BMI  Emerging BMI  U.S. Real Estate
Date
1999-12-31     0.926819         0.882021      0.298016               0.0
2000-01-31     0.463410         0.882021      0.298016               1.0
2000-02-29     0.463410         0.882021      0.298016               0.5
2000-03-31     0.926819         0.882021      0.298016               1.0
2000-04-28     0.926819         0.441010      0.000000               1.0

```
        Commodity  Gold  US Bonds
```

Date
1999-12-31        1.0   1.0  0.051282
2000-01-31        1.0   1.0  0.232785
2000-02-29        1.0   1.0  0.258426
2000-03-31        1.0   0.5  0.025641
2000-04-28        1.0   0.5  0.244795

Comment: Wait, so you just want your data all on one figure instead of one figure for each data?  If that's the case, you may want to consider taking the creation of a new figure out of your loop...

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code is causing the issue:

```
for index in weights.columns:    
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 6))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
```

For every column it is creating a new figure and a new axis on that figure. Instead you should return to your first instinct with the `axarr` and then when you iterate the columns in your dataframe, assign one of the axes of that array to a variable on which to plot the data in that column.

One dummy example looks like this:

```
# Create array of 8 subplots
f, axarr = plt.subplots(4, 2, figsize=(10,10))

# Create dummy data for my example
new_dict = {c: np.random.randint(low=1, high=10, size=40) for c in ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']}

df = pd.DataFrame(new_dict)

# Enumerate columns, providing index and column name
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):

    # Select subplot from list generated earlier
    ax = axarr.flat[i]

    # Select column and plot data on subplot axis
    df[col].hist(ax=ax)
```

[image: Subplots]

Editing the relevant parts of your code, I think you want:

```
for i, col in enumerate(weights.columns):    

    ax = axarr.flat[i]

    ax.set_ylabel('{} One month forward return'.format(col))

    ...

    plt.title('One Month Forward {} Returns Versus Total Exposure'.format(col))
    plt.scatter(weights_scaled[col], forward_returns[col], marker = 'o')
```